# On Heroku, can I get an email out of the scheduler output?

Tags: heroku, cron

Let's say I want to run this simple script every 5 min and get the output sent to my email ?

On a usual server I'd simply do:

```
$ cat echo.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello"

$ crontab -l
*/5 * * * * /whatever/bin/echo.sh
```

This would send me an email with the script name as the subject and `Hello` as a body every 5 minutes.

How do I get the same behavior on Heroku ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution that send you an email every 10 min. The heroku scheduler doesn't provide shorter intervals. Install this two add-ons:

1. https://addons.heroku.com/sendgrid (Send the email)

   ```
   heroku addons:add sendgrid
   ```
2. https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler (Schedule the job)

   ```
   heroku addons:add scheduler
   ```

Then you add the flowing script *mail.sh* to your app:

```
#!/bin/sh
SGTO=receiver@example.com
SGTONAME='Some Name'
SGSUBJECT='Email Subject'
SGFROM=from@example.com
SGTEXT='Email Text'
curl -d "to=${SGTO}&toname=${SGTONAME}&subject=${SGSUBJECT}&text=${SGTEXT}&from=${SGFROM}&api_user=${SENDGRID_USERNAME}&api_key=${SENDGRID_PASSWORD}" https://api.sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json
```

Finally go to your scheduler and add a new job. Specify `bash mail.sh` as the task.